# Android: Set background of subview in custom view

Tags: java, android, overriding, android-custom-view, custom-view

So I've got this problem in my custom view. I'm trying to create a custom `RelativeLayout` with an infinite scrolling animation. To achieve this, I've created a layout `backgroundscrollrelativelayout.xml` like so:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mainTile"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/topTile" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/leftTile" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/diagonalTile" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The idea is that the `ImageView`s will translate their position on an animation update callback.

I've created the `BackgroundScrollRelativeLayout.java` like so:

```
public class BackgroundScrollRelativeLayout extends RelativeLayout {
final int layoutToUse = R.layout.backgroundscrollrelativelayout;
final int mainTileId = R.id.mainTile;
final int leftTileId = R.id.leftTile;
final int topTileId = R.id.topTile;
final int diagonalTileId = R.id.diagonalTile;

final float valueStart = 0.0f;
final float valueEnd = 1.0f;
final long animationDuration = 50000L;

private Context mContext;
private ValueAnimator scrollAnimator;

private ImageView mainTile;
private ImageView leftTile;
private ImageView topTile;
private ImageView diagonalTile;


public BackgroundScrollRelativeLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
    mContext = context;
    acquireViewsInLayout();
    initializeAnimator();
    scrollAnimator.start();
}

public BackgroundScrollRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    mContext = context;
    acquireViewsInLayout();
    initializeAnimator();
    scrollAnimator.start();
}


public BackgroundScrollRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    mContext = context;
    acquireViewsInLayout();
    initializeAnimator();
    scrollAnimator.start();
}

@Override
public void setBackgroundColor(int color) {
    // Not supported
}

@Override
public void setBackgroundResource(int resid) {
    // Not supported
}


@Override
public void setBackground(Drawable background) {
    mainTile.setBackground(background);
    leftTile.setBackground(background);
}

/*
@Override
public void setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable background) {
    //super.setBackgroundDrawable(background);
    //mainTile.setBackground(background);
    //leftTile.setBackground(background);
}*/

// Intent: Inflate the layout associated with this View
private void inflateLayout(){
    // TO inflateLayout, we connect the inflater to context, then we call inflate the layout associated
    // with this view

    //LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    //inflater.inflate(layoutToUse, this);
    inflate(getContext(), layoutToUse, this);
}

// Intent: Find all Views in Layout
private void findAllViewsById(){
    mainTile = (ImageView)this.findViewById(mainTileId);
    leftTile = (ImageView)this.findViewById(leftTileId);
    topTile = (ImageView)this.findViewById(topTileId);
    diagonalTile = (ImageView)this.findViewById(diagonalTileId);
}

// Intent: Concretely acquire all Views in Layout
private void acquireViewsInLayout(){
    // TO acquireViewsInLayout, we inflate the layout,
    // then we find the view of each known view id and save the view
    inflateLayout();
    findAllViewsById();
}

// Intent: Initialize animator properties
private void initializeAnimator(){
    // TO initializeAnimator, we set how the animator will keep track of animation,
    // then we set the animation repeat type, then we set the type of interpolation,
    // then we set the animation duration, then we apply animation update listener
    scrollAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(valueStart, valueEnd);
    scrollAnimator.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
    scrollAnimator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    scrollAnimator.setDuration(animationDuration);
    addScrollAnimatorUpdateListener();
}

// Intent: Add an update listener to the scroll animator
private void addScrollAnimatorUpdateListener(){
    // TO addScrollAnimatorUpdateListener, we add an update listener to scroll animator
    scrollAnimator.addUpdateListener( new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            // Do something...
            updateScrollAnimation();
        }
    });

}

private void updateScrollAnimation(){
    float progress = (float)scrollAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
    float widthOfTile = mainTile.getWidth();

    float moveInXAxis = widthOfTile * progress;

    mainTile.setTranslationX(moveInXAxis);
    leftTile.setTranslationX(moveInXAxis - widthOfTile);


    // Ignore the rest for now
    topTile.setTranslationY(-1.0f);
    diagonalTile.setTranslationX(-1.0f);
    diagonalTile.setTranslationY(-1.0f);

}



}
```

I use my custom view like so in an activity:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.martianstudio.adivinaque.AppSettingsActivity">

<com.martianstudio.adivinaque.BackgroundScrollRelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/main_activity_animation_icon" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The goal of this is to allowing the user to specify the background that they want to scroll with `android:background`. I do not want the parent `RelativeLayout` to take on this drawable as a background. Instead, I want the `ImageViews` to set the drawable as the background. I have overridden the `setBackground` in my custom view so that only the `ImageView`s set the drawable as the background and not the `RelativeLayout` (as it would by default).

```
@Override
public void setBackground(Drawable background) {
    mainTile.setBackground(background);
    leftTile.setBackground(background);
}
```

However, I get this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException at com.martianstudio.adivinaque.BackgroundScrollRelativeLayout.setBackground
```

This says that `mainTile` in `setBackground` has not been set (it is null). In my `findAllViewsById()` I explicitly write `this.mainTile = (ImageView)this.findViewById(mainTileId);`, where `mainTileId = R.id.mainTile`, and I inflate the layout in `inflateLayout()`. Both of these methods are called in the constructors of the class. It seems to me that for some reason, it cannot find the `ImageView` with the `mainTile` Id when I override the `setBackground` method like I do. If I don't override the `setBackground` method, I do not get a NullPointerException, however, it defaults to the default setBackground method, which is what I do not want. Am I missing somthing?

Any help will be appreciated :). Thank you!

Comment: Maybe it works like this: `this` in `inflateLayout()` is the rooView contain customView. The rootView don't contain ImageView mainTile,leftTile..etc. So if you use `this` to `findViewById` will return `null`.

Comment: @HoangNguyen I have mainTile.setTranslationX(moveInAxis) later in the updateScrollAnimation function and it does not complain about a NullPointer. I think that when setBackground() is called by the Android system, it does it before it inflates the layout so that findViewById returns null. I'm thinking I'm going to have to get the drawable resource via attrs. I'll check back if I find anything. Thanks for commenting!